# Javascript sorting array day name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm going to sort day name based on array list day with below code:

```js
var dayList = ['Mon', 'Fri', 'Sun', 'Wed', 'Sat'];

const map = {
   'Mon': 1,'Tue': 2,'Wed': 3,'Thu': 4,'Fri': 5,'Sat': 6, 'Sun': 7
};

dayList.sort((a, b) => {
   return map[a.day] - map[b.day];
});

console.log(dayList);
```

But it show me same sort result to :
`[ "Mon", "Fri", "Sun", "Wed", "Sat"]`

It should be like this:

`[ "Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]`

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access *day* property from the elements in `dayList` which really does not exists and returns `undefined`.
You should compare day names directly.

Change:

```
return map[a.day] - map[b.day];
```

To:

```
return map[a] - map[b];
```

**Code Example:**

```js
var dayList = ['Mon', 'Fri', 'Sun', 'Wed', 'Sat'];

const map = {
   'Mon': 1,'Tue': 2,'Wed': 3,'Thu': 4,'Fri': 5,'Sat': 6, 'Sun': 7
};

dayList.sort((a, b) => {
   return map[a] - map[b];
});

console.log(dayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small mistake

Change:

```
return map[a.day] - map[b.day];
```

to:

```
return map[a] - map[b];
```